# OpenCV can't open network stream from gstreamer created by raspberry

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, gstreamer

I'm trying to open an unicast udp stream from my Raspberry pi using Gstreamer. This stream will be received on a Windows PC using a C++ application with OpenCV. This is the shellscript i use on the raspberry to start the stream:

```
raspivid -t 0 -h 1080 -w 1920 -fps 30 -hf -vf -n -b 6000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvvv  fdsrc ! h264parse !  rtph264pay config-interval=5 pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.0.101 port=5001
```

I am able to receive and display the footage on my Windows PC using a batch file like this:

```
@echo off
cd C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5001 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false
```

To be able to use this stream in my C++ application I use Opencv. I am not familiar with opening a stream using Opencv. I'm trying to open the stream using the following code:

```
    cv::VideoCapture cap("udp://@:5001");
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        printf("=ERR= can't create video capture\n");
        return -1;
    }
```

When I run my application it gets stuck (not crashing) at cv::VideoCapture cap("udp://@:5001"); every time. I'm not sure what the input parameters are between the quotation marks. When I wireshark the stream I get this result:

> Source:192.186.0.103 Destination:192.168.0.101 Protocol:UDP Length:1442 Info:35946->5001 Len=1400

Obviously this is just one of the many packages.

Can anyone help me with those input parameters or show me another way to open the stream in OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCv supports gstreamer and you can input pipes to VideoCapture. What you need to do is finish your pipe with appsink.

In your case you might use

```
const char* pipe = "udpsrc port=5001 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! appsink"
cv::VideoCapture cap(pipe);
```